# DataGridView BackColor not setting on initialise, but sets on refresh

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I'm creating a simple address book project which will fetch contacts from sql server and display these in a datagridview. When the program first loads, it automatically gets the contacts from the database and populates the grid. I have a method that styles the grid after population - it simply sets some grid properties which all seem to have an affect except the default cell style back color which at first does nothing.

However, when I clear the grid through a custom method and then repopulate the grid through calling the same method as I do when the program first loads, the back color of the grid sets correctly which seems absolutely bizarre. Here's my code:

```
private void BindGridWithContacts() //Populate grid with list of contact objects - ordered by address id
{
    bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Contacts);

    List<Contacts> sortedList = contacts.OrderBy(x => x.AddressId).ToList();
    contacts = new BindingList<Contacts>(sortedList);    //Orders the list of contacts by ID

    foreach (var contact in contacts) //Add each contact object to binding source
    {
        bindingSource.Add(contact);
    }

    grdContacts.DataSource = bindingSource; //data grids datasource = binding source
    grdContacts.StyleGrid();
}
```

I've read elsewhere on stack overflow that it can be tricky to style datagrids that are bound to a datasource so at first I just accepted it wouldn't be possible. But then once I called my clear grid method:

```
private void ClearGrid()
{
    grdContacts.DataSource = null;
    bindingSource.DataSource = null;
    bindingSource.Clear();
}
```

And then call the BindGridWithContacts() method again, the grid styles with my desired colours. Here is my StyleGrid() method:

```
public void StyleGrid()
{
        //Colour rows - currently not working
        for (int i = 0; i < this.RowCount; i++)
        {
            this.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = i % 2 != 0 ? Color.Lavender : Color.AliceBlue;
        }

        //Set Column Widths
        this.Columns["AddressId"].Width = 70;
        this.Columns["EmailAddress"].Width = 150;
        this.Columns["Hobby"].Width = 148;
        this.Columns["Forename"].Width = 115;
        this.Columns["Surname"].Width = 115;

        this.ReadOnly = true;
        this.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        this.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
}
```

Note: the grid will style properly every time the style grid method is called except the first time.

Any suggestions?? Thanks

Comment: Check if this.RowCount <= 0.  The Style Grid is probably being called before rows/columns are to DGV during the constructor of the DGV.  You are probably getting an exception when the constructor for DGV is running.  Simple add an If to your code to return if there are no rows in the DGV.

Comment: I've stepped through the Stylegrid() method and it loops through the same amount of rows each time - same code being hit but different outcomes. @jdweng

Comment: It is not the clear that is fixing the issue.  It is setting the DataSource = null.  The paint event get called when changing the DataSource which updates the Style.  A trick to get DGV to repaint is to set the DataSource to null and then back to the real source.  The real cause of your issue is you are doing the binding too early in the code.

Comment: I've tried setting the grdContacts.DataSource to null after I call BindGridWithContacts and then calling BindGridWithContacts again which seems to have no effect. I'm not sure what you mean when you say I'm binding too early? I didn't know there were good and bad times to bind data @jdweng

Comment: I said DataSource not FindGridWithContracts.  Not sure where code is being called (before, during, after constructor).  You can't call from the Initialize method.  It must be in a load method or other method after Initialize.

Comment: Ohhh I see what you mean now! I thought you meant the constructor for my grid rather than the form. You're right, I was calling BindGridWithContacts in the forms constructor. I've now implemented the form load method and called it there and it works perfectly. Thanks very much